# Python UDP sockets: Broadcast works but Unicast doesn't

Tags: python, sockets, udp

#### Setup

I am trying to send control commands to a sensor using UDP packets on an Ethernet network.

The sensor has hard-coded source IP and port number that it will only reply to, thus I must bind the port before sending. And since I have several interfaces on my machine I must also bind the IP address. A sample code is presented below.

```
import socket

DST_IP = "..."
SRC_IP = "..."
PORT_NO = .

message = "..."

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

sock.bind((SRC_IP, PORT_NO))
sock.connect((DST_IP, PORT_NO))

sock.sendto(bytes(message, "utf-8"), (DST_IP, PORT_NO))
sock.sendto(bytes(message, "utf-8"), ("255.255.255.255", PORT_NO))

print("src ", sock.getsockname()) # verify binding successful
print("dst ", sock.getpeername()) # verify connecting successful

sock.close()
```

I am monitoring the packets using Wireshark and checking for the sent data to verify that the commands were successful.

#### Problem

- After binding and connecting, I cannot detect a unicast on Wireshark but only the broadcast.
- If I don't bind, the program will choose a different interface and the sending will be successful
- I tried to disable all network interfaces except the one I need and try to run the program without binding the IP or port and nothing was sent in unicast but only in broadcast

I am out of ideas for debugging. Suggestions?

Comment: "If I don't bind, the program will choose a different interface and the sending will be successful" suggests that there is a mismatch between bound IP (src) address and target IP address or a routing parameter is messed up on your system. If you do not bind a src IP, the kernel should perform a route lookup (on the target IP) to find the proper interface to reach the target (this would establish a correct src IP too -- that assigned to the interface). The fact that it is not choosing the one you think it should indicates an addressing problem (an incorrect netmask might do it, for example).

Comment: That is really unfortunate, I have no access to the how the sensor is internally operating. My network configuration on the PC is correct I double and triple checked. Seems I will have to craft packets and send them using pcap. Thanks for the insight.